# Bad Request: ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported

Tags: erlang, cassandra, ejabberd, cql3

I need to fetch records from a table, which contain secondary index.But I get "Bad Request: ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported." error. I know this feature is not supported by CQL3 in cassandra server.How can I achieve this functionality?

Following are my table structure and index creating and select queries.

1.To create Table in cassandra:

```
    CREATE COLUMNFAMILY message_log(conversationid bigint,starttime timestamp,flag boolean,user_id text,expert_id text,conv_initiator_id text,message text,PRIMARY KEY(conversationid,starttime)) ;
```

2.To create index :
    CREATE INDEX message_log_idx_conv_initiator_id ON message_log (conv_initiator_id);

```
CREATE INDEX message_log_idx_flag ON message_log (flag);
```

3.To fetch records from table:
   select conversationid,user_id,expert_id,message from message_log where conv_initiator_id = 'manoj@1921.168.1.64' AND flag = true ORDER BY starttime ASC ALLOW FILTERING.

```
I get "Bad Request: ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported.", when I run 3rd query.
```

My Erlang part of my module is:

get_chat_history_by_userid(From)->

```
{ok, Pid} = seestar_session:start_link("localhost", 9042),      
QryUse = "USE mykeyspace;", 
case seestar_session:perform(Pid, QryUse, one) of 
    {ok,_Result} ->         
        FromJid = From#jid.luser++"@"++From#jid.lserver,            
        Flag = true,        
        QueryFinal=lists:concat(["select conversationid,user_id,expert_id,message from message_log 
        where conv_initiator_id = ","'",FromJid ,"'", " AND flag =",Flag," ORDER BY starttime ASC"," ALLOW FILTERING"]),            
            case seestar_session:perform(Pid,QueryFinal,one) of 
                {ok,_RecordList} ->                                  
                    {rows,_ColumnNames,_Records} = _RecordList,                     
                    ?INFO_MSG("selecting records from database using userid    ~p",[_Records]),
                    _Records;   
                {error,_Error} ->
                    ?INFO_MSG("Error occured while selecting records from database using userid~p",[_Error])
            end;                    
    {error,_Error} ->
        ?INFO_MSG(" Error occured while executing use query ~p",[_Error])
end.
```

Comment: Where is the Erlang part in your question?